# Random login field in localhost:8080

Tags: java, spring, localhost

I am building a Spring project, and when I run it, in browser at localhost:8080 I get this random Login field. How do I get rid of this? I have no html,css/front-end written whatsoever. When I try to go to my addresses like /all, it just redirects me to /login

[Login field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1wst.jpg)

Comment: How can we tell you what's wrong with your code without looking at **_your code_**? Please post minimal, reproducible code so that we could provide objective answers rather than resort to guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is spring boot and you are using `spring-boot-starter-security` along with `spring-boot-starter-web`, by default you will be redirected to this security page. To login you can use `user` as the username and the password will be printed in your console

```
INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.getOrDeducePassword -

Using generated security password:
```

See here how to disable the login: [How to disable spring-security login screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636368/how-to-disable-spring-security-login-screen)